# GCC proper visibility for shared object written in C++

Tags: gcc, strip, objdump

I have a huge project written in C++. It's all split into multiple static libraries that are eventually linked into one final shared library which has to export only a few simple functions.

If I do objdump of that final .so I see all my internal names etc. Because it uses long class names and namespaces these strings become excessively long and as a result final binary is big.

So, my question is how do I do it properly with GCC to make sure that all these internal functions do not show up in the final binary?

I'm aware about all these GCC-specific visibility modifiers, I use -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden, I use -Wl,--no-whole-archive. I disable c++ exceptions and rtti (-fno-exceptions -fno-rtti) but i still can't get GCC to generate my final .so that doesn't contain names of my namespaces and classes that aren't supposed to be there at all!

I tried to use -Wl,--version-script= to control which functions should be visible, but still I see lot's of internal names in final stripped shared object. I read multiple similar entries on SO, but don't see anything that does the job.
Note: I compile for multiple platforms (Linux, Windows, iPhone etc) and only on windows in VS I don't have any problems.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to try the `--retain-symbols-file` linker option when linking the final .so file (`-Wl,--retain-symbols-file=filename`) to specify JUST the symbols you want to keep (export) and delete everything else.  The file is just a text file with symbols (one per line) to keep.

Comment: I'll try this option now to see if the binary will run. From simple test I see that names of imported functions from other shared libs aren't in the binary anymore. Do I need to list imported names as well?

Comment: Chris, it seems that the option that I needed. final .so got slimmer by a couple of megs and nm list only symbols that I put into exports file. First issue: I use many static libs and some of the exports have to come from these static libs, and for some reason these symbols from static libs do not get exported. To fix it I had to use whole-archive option to force all functions from these libs to be exported.

Comment: The second issue is that even nm now lists only functions from exports file, if I use objdump I still get private names from my c++ code. For example: _ZN20RCSFTServiceImplPeer12onFTProgressERKN3RCS12FileTransferEy and my goal is to make whatever so that these strings aren't in the final binary.